# How Does printf change the output of my code

Tags: c, printf

I am writing a simple code to find the sum of the odd and even numbers till a given number.Please ignore my code if it does not get the right answers.The issue I am facing is that a simple printf changes the entire output of my code. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int num,i,sum_e,sum_o;
printf("\nEnter the number\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
sum_e=0;
sum_o=0;
for (i=1;i<=num;i++)
    printf("\n value of remainder = %d",i); // printf causing the change
if (i%2==0)
    {
        sum_e+=i;
    }
    else 
    {
        sum_o+=i;
    }
printf("\nsum of all odd numbers till %d = %d\n",num,sum_o);
printf("\nsum of all even numbers till %d = %d\n",num,sum_e);
return 0;
}
```

When I remove the printf("value of remainder") this is the output :

> Enter the number
>   3
>
> sum of all odd numbers till 3 = 4
>
> sum of all even numbers till 3 = 2

When I add the printf("value of remainder") this is the output :

> Enter the number
>
> 3
>
> value of remainder = 1
>
> value of remainder = 2
>
> value of remainder = 3
>
> sum of all odd numbers till 3 = 0
>
> sum of all even numbers till 3 = 4

My question is that how can a simple printf mess or massively change the output of the code . Please help . Thanks . PS Apologies in advance if the question was not formatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the braces around for `loop` to hold the `if-else` statement. Otherwise `if-else` is executed once. That is not what you wan't.

Correct way to do it:

```
for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {
    printf("\n value of remainder = %d",i); // printf causing the change
    if (i%2==0)
    {
        sum_e+=i;
    }
    else 
    {
        sum_o+=i;
    }
}
```

Otherwise earlier you got either one of the `sum_e` or `sum_o` `0` and another containing the value `num+1`.

When you remove the `printf` statement that `if-else` block is executed on every iteration which is why it gives correct result.

---

From standard you can see `$6.8.5`

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement;
```

On every iteration the `statement` is executed. An iteration statement (in this case `for` statement) causes a `statement` called the loop body to be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression (the comparison part) compares equal to 0.

Now earlier you place a single expression statement (`printf`). Later you replaced with the selection statement.(`if-else`).

So the key idea is only a statement is executed. And that was different in both of the cases you shown (that's why the result differed). In my shown example snippet in place of `statement` - a `compound statement` is being added. `{..}`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you should use opening and closing braces after the for statement, you can emit the use of braces if you have only a single line of code after the for statement, same goes with the if statement,

```
if(condition)
expression 1;
expression 2;
```

evaluates only expression 1, but if you want both of them to be evaluated then use

```
if(condition){
expression 1;
expression2;
}
```